# Tab delineated python 3 .txt file reading

Tags: python, csv, tabs, tuples

I am having a bit of trouble getting started on an assignment. We are issued a tab delineated .txt file with 6 columns of data and around 50 lines of this data. I need help starting a list to store this data in for later recall. Eventually I will need to be able to list all the contents of any particular column and sort it, count it, etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit; I really haven't done much besides research on this kinda stuff, I know ill be looking into csv, and i have done single column .txt files before but im not sure how to tackle this situation. How will I give names to the separate columns? how will I tell the program when one row ends and the next begins?

Comment: have a look at the `csv` module

Answer (score 2):

The dataframe structure in [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) basically does exactly what you want. It's highly analogous to the data frame in R if you're familiar with that. It has built in options for subsetting, sorting, and otherwise manipulating tabular data.

It reads [directly from csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) and even automatically reads in column names. You'd call:

```
read_csv(yourfilename, 
         sep='\t',     # makes it tab delimited
         header=1)     # makes the first row the header row.
```

Works in Python 3.

Comment: My data has no headers int he .txt file, might i be able to create them for the 6 columns of data?

Comment: Yes, in that case you just call `read_csv(yourfilename, sep='\t', names=['header1', 'header2', ...])`. Documentation is here: http://pandas.sourceforge.net/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a csv like the following.

```
 1       2       3       4       5       6
 1       2       3       4       5       6
 1       2       3       4       5       6
 1       2       3       4       5       6
 1       2       3       4       5       6
```

You can read them into a dictionary like so:

```
>>> import csv
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(open('test.csv','r'), fieldnames= ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'],  dialect='excel-tab')
>>> for row in reader:
...     print row    
{'col6': '6', 'col4': '4', 'col5': '5', 'col2': '2', 'col3': '3', 'col1': '1'}   
{'col6': '6', 'col4': '4', 'col5': '5', 'col2': '2', 'col3': '3', 'col1': '1'}   
{'col6': '6', 'col4': '4', 'col5': '5', 'col2': '2', 'col3': '3', 'col1': '1'}   
{'col6': '6', 'col4': '4', 'col5': '5', 'col2': '2', 'col3': '3', 'col1': '1'}   
{'col6': '6', 'col4': '4', 'col5': '5', 'col2': '2', 'col3': '3', 'col1': '1'}
```

But Pandas library might be better suited for this. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files

Comment: Thanks for this, that really helps! but in my data there are no headers, is there a way to assign headers to the columns without altering the original .txt file?

Comment: Yes, DictReader has an optional argument that can be used to pass in the fieldnames. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job better suited to a database. You should just use something like PostgreSQLs `COPY FROM` operation to import the CSV data into a table then use python + SQL for all your sorting, searching and matching needs.

If you feel a real database is overkill there's still options like SQLlite and BerkleyDB which both have python modules.

EDIT: BerkelyDB is deprecated but [anydbm](http://docs.python.org/library/anydbm.html#module-anydbm) is similiar in concept.

Comment: Yeah, I could do this in ArcGIS quite easily, but I'm required to use Python 3 for this, any ideas?

Comment: You can still use python to control the queries. If you mean to only use python then you'd just be implementing a database in python which is hardly an efficient use of time or resources. How do you feel about the berkleydb/sqlite options?

Comment: Ahhh, it's gotta be in Python 3. I know there are a lot more efficient ways to do this kind of thing haha. but sadly it must be with python3... :/

Comment: Then I'd have to say your question is overly broad and your requirements confusing. The `anydbm` module, and specifically the `dbm.dumb` module are python modules (dumbdbm is even written in python code). They are "in Python 3" in every sense of the word. The "databases" they use are just files on your disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a db for 50 lines and 6 colums is overkill, so here's my idea:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
from operator import itemgetter


def get_records_from_file(path_to_file):
    """
    Read a tab-deliminated file and return a
    list of dictionaries representing the data.
    """
    records = []
    with open(path_to_file, 'r') as f:
        # Use the first line to get names for columns
        fields = [e.lower() for e in f.readline().split('\t')]

        # Iterate over the rest of the lines and store records
        for line in f:
            record = {}
            for i, field in enumerate(line.split('\t')):
                record[fields[i]] = field
            records.append(record)

    return records


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'so.txt')
    records = get_records_from_file(path)

    print('Number of records: {0}'.format(len(records)))

    s = sorted(records, key=itemgetter('id'))
    print('Sorted: {0}'.format(s))
```

For storing records for later use, look into Python's [pickle library](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)--that'll allow you to preserve them as Python objects.

Also, note I don't have Python 3 installed on the computer I'm using right now, but I'm pretty sure this'll work on Python 2 or 3.